# Can't understand apache access log entry with ftp referer, may be security issue

Tags: apache-http-server, ftp, logging

I have a godaddy-hosted domain/web page. It has no index.html page, only private pages requiring links being supplied by me, with images embedded that come from files on my home PC served by apache, its log is what's in question. I found this rather unusual access log entry, obfuscations obvious. The source IP is the real IP and is a godaddy address--used by the company.

```
64.202.160.225 - - [15/May/2018:14:59:44 -0500] "GET /dox/photo-in-privateindex.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 530135 "ftp://IP.Of.my.goddaddy-site/name-0f-my-godaddy-site.org/privateindex.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
```

My home PC apache server is on a completely separate, independent domain. No one should be able to ftp into my files at godaddy without an ID and password, and surly shouldn't be accessing files on my PC through ftp. Plus, is this an ftp access as it implies? How do you use ftp to get to a jpeg photo embedded in a page without downloading the page's html to copy the link, and they shouldn't be able to download the page via ftp. I tried and was asked for an ID and password.

I must be missing something. Or is godaddy using internal access somehow? There were 4 different private pages, 13 images in all, that were accessed this way, including one page named index.html.break. Over about half a minute. They knew what files were there. Would godaddy be digging around in my private files like this? The source of the hit is one of their IPs. They're not supposed to be doing that. Only one person had the private page links, but he didn't have the index.html.break page link, and definitely doesn't have the ID and password.

Any ides? Thanks for any help.

Comment: No luck.  Well, can anyone enlighten me on how, or whether, ftp can access a file in this manner?  There's lots of sites that you can ftp into with a standard web browser and download files, but I think they have to be set up to do that????